# Better duplicate closing on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, ios-app, duplicate-suggestions

Currently, flagging or voting to close as a duplicate on the iOS app gives you a simple text input to paste a question URL or ID. No duplicate suggestions, no search, [nothing but a text input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtIUw.jpg)

I know there are limitations on what can be implemented because of what is accessible through the API and there can be difficulties in implementing the UI for smaller devices. But, as I discovered yesterday, [the Android app already has duplicate suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284694/dupe-vtc-flag-dialog-on-android). So, can we implement:

1. **Duplicate suggestions, as the Android app already has.**
2. **A search UI similar to the full-site duplicate dialog.**

The suggestions already exist on the Android app so there shouldn't be any trouble porting that to iOS, and there is already search functionality elsewhere in the app so that shouldn't be a problem either. There is an existing feature-request: [Show post(s) already chosen as duplicate suggestions in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277933/307988) which would be far exceeded by this.

Comment: Even if it would simply allow you to pick the already suggested duplicate, that would be a major step up.

Comment: +1, a nightmare to do a VtC (duplicate) on the iOS, even after a year this questionis is asked.