# How to close as duplicate in the app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, mobile-app

When trying to close a question as a duplicate in the app, you are expected to enter a URL or number.  But, the app doesn't show numbers or URLs, and it doesn't show the previously selected duplicates (those chosen by others) either. This makes it very hard to use the app to close a question as a duplicate.

Please explain how you're supposed to use it if there's a shortcut I've missed, or add the option to get at the relevant info.

Comment: @RobertLongson — not really, but the whole issue is moot now since there is no further maintenance to be done on the Android or iOS apps, more's the pity.  Also, that post is mentioned/linked in the answer.

Comment: Yaakov says: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/282094

Comment: The close reason is incorrect.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou — the close reason is 'Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete'.  For this question, the "changes to the system" are SO's stance on the apps (see the linked MSE item written by Yaakov, referenced by Rob), and it is an accurate enough close reason for something that simply isn't going to be fixed…unless SO is actually going to revitalize the apps, but then the revitalization should take into account the usability issues such as this.  I'm not keen on having to close it, but it serves no purpose being kept open.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou: At a pinch, it could be closed instead as a duplicate of [Better duplicate closing in the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284720/better-duplicate-closing-on-the-ios-app), but that's not wholly appropriate as the other question has no answer whereas this one does.  At the moment, for me, the 'share' option doesn't work well.  I have to terminate the app after copying the duplicate link, then navigate back to the question I want to close.  That's painful; I seldom do it.  There are other problems in the iOS app that need to be fixed too, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "share" button underneath posts (as there is on the website). Click that and hit "Copy", then paste in the duplicate closing input.

You don't say which app (Android or iOS) but I believe it's the same in both (I only use iOS).

> [image]

---

*If you'd like a better duplicate UI give this an upvote: [Better duplicate closing on the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284720/better-duplicate-closing-on-the-ios-app) ;)*

Comment: I've duly up-voted the other; this is in part a duplicate of that.  And thanks for the information about the Share button.  It's one I've not otherwise needed; since I was closing, it didn't occur to me that sharing might help.

Comment: True, "sharing" isn't exactly the first thing that comes to mind when you're trying to close.